# Filtering Lists of Maybes

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monetjs

If I have a `Maybe<int>[]`, and I'd like to only take those values of the array which are not `None`, what is the best way to do that, and have typescript understand what it's getting?

I'm presuming the way to type that would be to say that I'm going to end up with `int[]`.

I could do:

```js
const x: int[] = [1, 2, 3, null]
  .map(Maybe.fromNull)
  .filter(x => !x.isNone())
  .map(x => x.getOrElse(-1)) // this ought not to ever require the default value
```

But this feels very clunky and verbose. I feel like I'm missing some better way of handling this.

Comment: Not sure there is a way to do this with native array methods. The array type (more abstractly) `Array<A | B>` but when you call `.filter()` to drop all `A`s the type doesn't change as `.filter()` returns the same type of the array. For TS only, you can use a type assertion but in your case the array actually contains concrete objects. All the `Maybe`s can't just know that they are not empty. It's a tricky problem to say the least.

Comment: By the way, you get a similar problem even outside JS/TS - I've seen it in Java and in C# when you try to use stream/LINQ operations the types can't really know what has been done in the chain up to then. You can do a `.filter(x => x.id != null)` and the later operations have no way of knowing that `id` is always set - they'd warn you if you try to dereference `.id` as if not null.

Comment: What is the difference of `null` and the `Maybe` tagged union? With the latter you don't have to check for `None` values, because the involved code always considers both cases. This applies until you fold or eliminate the tagged union, as you did with `getOrElse`. The given example doesn't use `Maybe` as it is intended.

Comment: @bob For the code I'm using the problem arises when I come to interact with some code which requires an `int[]`, for instance; in this instance I'm happy to drop anything from the list which doesn't contain a value

Comment: @VLAZ That's an interesting perspective; considering the type as `A | B` is probably the better approach for the question, the fact that it's a `Maybe` in this instance is perhaps a distraction

Comment: @OliverRadini Oh, OK. I just took the code as an example, but if you literally have this situation where you have `Array<number | null>` and want to convert to `Array<number>`, then you don't need the `Maybe`.

Comment: @VLAZ The code is an example for sure; what I meant in my other comments is that the problem seems to lie with `filter` not changing the type

Comment: @OliverRadini well, `filter` can't really change the type, it should preserve it. Yes, *logically* in this case, you could go from `Array<int | null>` to `Array<int>` using `.filter(x => x !== null)` but think of the wider case - you could also be doing `x !== 3` in which case you cannot safely change from `int | null` to `int`. There are infinitely many predicates that still produce an `int | null` array afterwards. I don't think TS is able to evaluate the predicate and decide that the result is going to eliminate one of the types for the union.

Comment: @VLAZ I agree completely; `filter` changing types wouldn't really make sense. I'll play around with the problem a little more and see what I can come up with, for the record the actual issue I'm having is trying to work with a relational data structure on the front end; objects relate to other object via Ids, but there's not really a guarantee that the object with a given id exists, which I why I started using maybes here

Comment: If it helps, in C# the only solution I saw was an explicit casting. It's even in the API, you can do something like `collection.Where(x => x != null).Cast<int>()` (`Where` == `filter`) to change from `int?` to `int`. You can probably implement `Cast()` as `.map(x => x as int)`. Which isn't very pretty but it's the only thing you can do with native arrays - `filter` can't change types of data but `map` can.

Comment: @VLAZ It's interesting that you point that out; I've used it that feature in C# before but hadn't linked the two in my head. It's an interesting problem to solve, not sure that I've yet seen a way of doing it that is ideal

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on the particular implementation of Maybe so I'm including one I'm using below. Basically right now you need to explicitly annotate function as a type guard for this to work. There was a talk of support `not T` types that would be required for `!isNone()` to work, but hasn't happen so far. The code below does work though:

```
const MaybeTag = Symbol("Maybe");

type Nothing<T> = { [MaybeTag]?: T; name: "Nothing" } ;
type Just<T> ={ [MaybeTag]?: T; name: "Just";  value: T } ;
type Maybe<T> = Just<T> | Nothing<T>

const Maybe = {
    Just<T>(value: T): Just<T> {
        return { name: "Just", value };
    },
    Nothing<T = never>(): Nothing<T> {
        return { name: "Nothing" };
    },
    isNothing<T>(maybe: Maybe<T>): maybe is Nothing<T> {
        return maybe.name === "Nothing";
    },
    isJust<T>(maybe: Maybe<T>): maybe is Just<T> {
        return maybe.name === "Just";
    },
    fromNull<T>(value: T | null | undefined): Maybe<T> {
        if (value == null) return Maybe.Nothing();
        return Maybe.Just(value);
    }
}

const x: number[] = [1, 2, 3, null]
  .map(Maybe.fromNull)
  .filter(Maybe.isJust)
  .map(x => x.value) // x is Just<number> as expected

const x: number[] = [1, 2, 3, null]
  .map(Maybe.fromNull)
  // Note the explicit type guard
  .filter(function<T>(x: Maybe<T>): x is Just<T> { 
    return !Maybe.isNothing(x);
  })
  .map(x => x.value) // x is Just<number> as expected
```